# Trigger middleware on mass operations in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, middleware

Based on the documentation for Mongoose it seems that middleware is only triggered by operations on the models, i.e. not those that communicate with the database directly.  This means that if I wanted to trigger middleware for a mass removal, for example, I'd have to do:

```
Users.find().exec(function (err, users) {
    users.forEach(function (user) { user.remove(); });
});
```

Is there a better way to perform mass operations on models in Mongoose that still triggers middleware?

Comment: I asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201940/denormalization-with-mongoose-how-to-synchronize-changes/
I am not sure my solution helps at all, but it's an approach.

Comment: I know it's not the same but I feel that refactoring some code to NodeJS event system could be helpful in certain situations. You could for instance call a query that retrieves all documents you will remove (or at least only the fields you care about), then call the remove operation, then trigger a DocumentRemoved event for each document and have somebody else listen to it.